# Does Stack Exchange have any testers?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange-team

I was viewing Stack Exchange profile on Careers and I found that SE had 10 out of 12 in the Joel Test.

[image]

The interesting thing that I find here is that the SE does not have testers. For a company that boasts of providing the best working conditions for developers, this does not seem to make sense.

Does SE totally depends on hallway usability testing or is this information incorrect?
No offense meant. I am just curious.

Comment: Related discussion (with responses to your question, although not official ones): https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=4269107

Comment: Aren't we SE's testers?

Comment: @Yannis Yes, and they don't have to pay us!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We don't have any software testers [on the roster](https://stackexchange.com/about/team) right now.

The Careers 2.0 team relies a fair bit on automated testing. The Q&A team makes liberal use of <s>human guinea pigs</s> valued MSO contributors. And of course, developer testing, which everyone should still do even if they have a fully staffed QA department.

Comment: Developer testing is the best type of all. It's real, not random, never fudged, and products always work on developer machines.

Comment: @slugster see ["Top Five (Wrong) Reasons You Don't Have Testers"](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000067.html). BTDTGTTS ([1](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/102652/31260 "get testers!"), [2](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/100882/31260 "get testers!"))